# Service недопустимый метод

Tags: java, android, service

Работаю в Service с Okhttp

```
Callback() {
     @Override
     public void onFailure (Call call, IOException e){

         Fon.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {

             }

         });

     }

     @Override
     public void onResponse (Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
         final String result = response.body().string();
         Fon.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {




             }

         });

     }

 });
```

подчеркивает `runOnUiThread` пишет что метод не разрешен, подскажите, как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак, у сервисов нет доступа к UI треду, кроме как из методов жизненного цикла, вызываемых системой.

Сервис должен оповещать кого надо, активити например, и она обновит UI.

Comment: Не совсем верно. UI-thread  - это главный поток приложения и сервис совершает все операции как раз в нём. Т.е., например, с API>14 приложение будет падать с `NetworkonMainThreadException` при попытке обратиться в сеть из сервиса не в новом, другом потоке. Также, если в сервисе делать тяжелые операции не в новом потоке, то приложение будет лагать и может упасть с ANR. И активити, коли запущена одновременно, будет тормозить. Т.е. тут дело в том, что метода `runOnUiThread` нет в сервисе, он есть только в активити.

Comment: Согласен, формулировка не совсем точная, но и вы с "сервис совершает все операции как раз в нём" не совсем правы. Дополню ответ.

Comment: Я руководствовался докой) https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Basics Предупреждение над заголовком `Basics`

Comment: Я не согласен с вами только в том, что "сервис совершает все операции" в UI-thread. Только методы жизненного цикла исполняются в нем, а это никак не "все операции" сервиса. Правильного сервиса :)

Comment: А, ну тут да, я немного не так выразился) Прошу считать, что там было "по умолчанию")